# Numpy subsetting and assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say you want to subset a NumPy array `fridge_items` for rows of tasty things that have a rating of higher than 7.

```
most_tasty_items = fridge_items[:,10] > 7)
```

You get back an array of boolean values.

If you then did:

```
fridge_items[most_tasty_items,:][:3,:]
```

What is going on here exactly when you index into fridge_items.
I'm familiar with doing array[1,2] and this returning what is at that given row and column.

Since `most_tasty_items` is a 1D array of boolean values, how do we index into that using the `[:3,:]`? If it were just a 1D array we could just say [:]. Not quite getting this, and why we give `:` as second parameter to `[most_tasty_items,:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you address the data with two couples of brackets, you are performing two operations,
the first brackets select a new array from the data and the second brackets addresses the new array.

```
In [71]: np.random.seed(2020) 
    ...: fridge = np.random.randint(11, size=(30, 5)) 
    ...: tasty = fridge_items[:,4] > 7 
    ...: tastyfridge = fridge[tasty,:]                                                    

In [72]: tastyfridge[:2,:], fridge[tasty][:2,:]                                           
Out[72]: 
(array([[ 8, 10,  9,  3,  7],
        [ 4,  7,  1,  4,  9]]),
 array([[ 8, 10,  9,  3,  7],
        [ 4,  7,  1,  4,  9]]))

In [73]:
```